# How to change the text of an alert message with JQuery icon

Tags: jquery

I like to change the text of an alert message with JQuery. My code looks like:

```
<p><span id="tips" class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span></p>

var tips = translate("Verwijder") + " " + $('#oms' + uploadId).text() + "?";
$('#tips').text(tips);
```

For some reason this does not work. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please provide more information. The code looks correct, perhaps your `span` is not in the visible area of your screen, perhaps `translate()` throws an error, so the subsequent code is not being executed. Perhaps perhaps perhaps...

Comment: Another possibility is, that there is already another element with the `id="tips"` somewhere before this element. Ids have to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, fixed it myself.

```
<div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span><p id="tips{$followNo}"></p></div>
```

This did the trick.